# Hibernate can't insert UUID to VARCHAR column

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, playframework

I am working on setting up a MySQL database and using Hibernate and Play Framework for the backend.
I am having problems with the IDs of entries. I defined my id column as `VARCHAR(36)`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `logaritmical`.`users` (
   `id` VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL,
   `username` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `email` TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`id` ASC)
);
```

Now, the `@Entity` class is like this:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class UserDO {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
   @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
   @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false, columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(36)")
   private UUID id;
    
   @Column
   private String username;
    
   @Column
   private String email;
}
```

When doing the insert, I get the following error: `Incorrect string value: '\xEF\xA5!\x89\xF3K...' for column 'id' at row 1`

If I change the column type and columnDefinition to `BINARY(16)` the insert works, but it has the disadvantage that the ID is not human-readable when doing selects.

Additional info:
`persistence.xml` looks like this:

```xml
<persistence-unit name="defaultPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
   <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
   <non-jta-data-source>DefaultDS</non-jta-data-source>
   <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect"/>
   </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

DB Configuration and versions of libraries looks like this:
`jpa.default=defaultPersistenceUnit`
`"org.hibernate" % "hibernate-entitymanager" % "5.4.24.Final",`
`"mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "8.0.22",`

What can be done to have the `UUID` working with `VARCHAR`? Is there something I am missing?

Comment: What hibernate dialect do you use?

Comment: I am using MySQL8Dialect. Editing to add this information s well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use the following definition:

```java
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class UserDO {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false, columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(36)")
    @Type(type = "uuid-char")
    private UUID id;

    // ...
}
```

It looks like that for your dialect `UUID` by default mapped to the `uuid-binary` [basic type](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#basic).

P.S. Please note that saving `UUID` PK as a string can lead to the performance issue, as it explained in [this article](https://tomharrisonjr.com/uuid-or-guid-as-primary-keys-be-careful-7b2aa3dcb439):

> Aside from the 9x cost in size (36 vs. 4 bytes for an int), strings don’t sort as fast as numbers because they rely on collation rules.

Comment: I just saw the later edit about using UUIDs as PK. Really opened my eyes! Will definitely reconsider this.